# How to aggregate test results from sub jobs in a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

## Problem

I  am using the jenkins pipeline tool with build job plugin to make a pipe from existing jobs created in JJB.

```
    timeout(time: 7, unit: 'MINUTES'){
    node {

             build job: 'Job-1'
        }
    }   
   post {
            always {
                junit 'results/**/*.xml'
            }
        }
    }
```

I would  like  to aggregate the  test results (junit) from these  jobs and  publish a report

I cannot  do this because  I  do not know  the  scope  of the  pipeline. In  a node pipeline environment  I  would  use the build number and  the  job ID to link to the  test results.  'results/**/*.xml' points to nothing.

## Versions

- Jenkins 2.60.1
- Pipeline: Job 2.12

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am also interesting on it.

Comment: put it subjob into its own stage: `stage(job) { build job: job ... junit '...xml'}`